# Counting gluons in a proton, are we sure measurement doesn't affect the number?

Tags: quantum-chromodynamics, strong-force, gluons

Regarding gluons in a hadron, when you look with one resolution you see a certain number, but looking closer you see some of these particles have split.
How are we actually looking at these? Can we be sure the act of measurement is not splitting these gluons? In other words, are we sure the energy of the measurement is not sufficient to split them?

Comment: How many gluons have we counted in the proton so far?